# udp program not working

Tags: java, networking

i tried my hands on networking and this is the first time i have understood some bit of it.i have a program with a client and server.What i want to do is that the server should send data continuously to a port and whenever there is any data in port say 2656 ,the client should read the data from that port and the data should be flushed from the port.I have created a server program and a client program but the client is not receiving any packet.I m running client and server on two different machines.

Server Program

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
 DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
    try {
      String host = "192.168.0.15";

    int count =1;
      byte[] message = "Java Source and Support".getBytes();

      // Get the internet address of the specified host
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

      // Initialize a datagram packet with data and address
for(;;)
{

      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message,   message.length,
          address, 2656);

      // Create a datagram socket, send the packet through it,          //close it.
     System.out.println("Sending data"+message.toString();
      dsocket.send(packet);
}
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
    finally
      {
      dsocket.close();
       }
  }
}
```

Client program

```
package saturdayTest;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class UDPReceive {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      int port = 2656;

      // Create a socket to listen on the port.
      DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
      while (true) {
         System.out.println("Waiting for  a packer");
        dsocket.receive(packet);

        String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
        System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName() + ": "
            + msg);


        packet.setLength(buffer.length);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this stackoverflow only..not a single comment uptil now..shocking

Comment: a few suggestions 1. make sure the two machines can ping each other. 2. make sure that the ports you are communicating on is open on the two hosts(may be the firewall is blocking the port). finally add more relevant tags to your question like socket, tcpsocket ...

Comment: Thanks akhilesh..firewall was the problem..solved it:)